# How to remove a column from an iTextSharp table

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

In my c# app, I have a function to generate a PDF document using [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), which includes a table of figures. The table (PdfPTable specifically) is populated and then inserted into the document. After it has been populated, under certain conditions, I would like to remove one of the columns - does anyone know how to do this?

I know I could conditionally exclude cells when populating the table, but this will be quite complex in my situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the tables in iTextSharp are generated a cell at a time I think it would be much easier to programmatically remove the 'column' at generation time rather than after it.

Answer (score 0):

I would test for the condition, then include or not include the column when the table is being created.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the column width to 0 so it does not appear by using the PdfPTable.SetWidths(float[])

For example

```
float[] ColumnWidths = new float[] { 10,0,10,0 };

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(ColumnWidths.Length);
table.SetWidths(ColumnWidths);
```

Now column 2 and 4 will no longer appear visually on the PDF, you can change the widths of the table at any point by passing a new float array to it.